# How can one infect/shutdown a Virtual Reality game using technology?

Tags: technology, games, virtual-reality

For a lack of better words, I’m looking for technical ways for a person to shutdown an entire VRMMORPG (Virtual Reality Massively Multiplayer Online Role-Playing Game) from afar. And by shutting down I mean something like infecting it with a virus or messing with the game mechanics to disable the game for other players without being present. This can either be temporary or permanent.

Since the game is VR, it’s played using a headset - the one where it alters your brain to make you experience a more realistic in-game experience. Users can fully dive in the game using this headset.

The world setting is in 2050 so technology is more advanced than now.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Edit: Everyone gave super useful ideas and information so I’m going to try to combine them.

Comment: Less than 30 minutes to accept an answer poses a serious limitation to the quality of the answers you will get.

Comment: Why not simply [DDoS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/what-is-a-ddos-attack/) the game servers?

Comment: git push origin master --force

Answer (score 6):

Years ago in the Second Life - a game/simulation which heavily relies on user-created content - someone let loose an object which simply replicated itself. In short order it replicated to the point of consuming significant server resources and thus causing problems.

Now one could say that any new games since then can and should protect against such things. But then one can also say that hacking / trouble-making is the art of finding ways around safeguards.

So we just need to presume that someone can find an exploit to allow a self-replicating object to proceed in your VRMMORPG. Then boom, server resources quickly get exhausted and the game effectively taken down - at least until the maintainers of the game can intervene and fix the situation.

Comment: This is really good information and a great suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Cut the power at the server farm for the game and you're done- no one can get map data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've watched Sword Art Online but that it has a similar plot line. I know it's an anime so it's not 100% real but you can get some ideas from it if you want. Besides watching a show for research is one of the best. (If you're interested it's on Netflix and Hulu)

In SAO the exit button is taken away by the creator after everyone has put on their headsets which was probably an added code the creator put in. This kept anyone from leaving and later was announced that everyone had to clear the boss level in order to get out. If anyone tampered with the headset it would essentially turn the players brain to mush thereby killing them. The code is what tells the computer what to do when an action is done.

You've probably heard of 1's and 0's being referred to as switches, that's what code is. I'll give you an example of a line of code from my Web Design Class. A simple one is the nav bar. The bar across the top of the website that takes you to different web pages. That word you click on is linked to another html page. 
For Example:  Contact Us 
 (This is what links to the Contact us page) Contact Us (this is the word you click on)  (this is the end tag)

If you forget the end tag or the ending > it might not show up on your nav bar or link properly.

A big part of computers are the code, if you can access the coding of the game and screw up some tags here a few lines of code there or insert a virus when a person does a certain action (especially if it's a common action like picking up a certain apple or opening a door) then it will infect a lot of players. And since it's a headset that taps into the brain, a malfunction can be bad if it affects that area of code. I'm not a coder but I'm taking a web design class and we're building websites from scratch with code so I have a small basis of understanding. With code, if you simply forget an end tag or parse something wrong it really screws up your code. And if you do it in crucial enough areas it won't show what is contained in the tags.

That was probably a lot more than you ever expected and the code I'm learning is web design so it's not game design but considering quite a few game are web based it might help you have a better idea or what you're looking for.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the long elaborative answer! I know SAO and how coding works, but the coding examples you gave was really helpful to know.

Answer (score 1):

### Have sex with one of the admins, and get their laptop while asleep. Then, use your admin privileges to insert said virus.

No need to use elaborate measures when you can just set a honey pot. You can just ignore all security measures with admin access.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Identify the targets.

  The targets can be the actual game server application, or the database it uses, or any one of the zillion libraries it uses, or the operating system on which it runs, or the virtualization software on which the operating systems run, or the management component of the virtualization software, or the operating system on which the virtualization software runs, or the management subsystem of the physical machines, or the management subsystem of the storage arrays, or the software of the storage arrays, or the firmware of the network switches and so on.
- Step 2: Identify one or more vulnerabilities in the targets identified at step 1.

  A vulnerability is either a design error or a coding error, which provides a potential way for an attacker to gain control or disable one of targets.
- Step 3: Design one or more exploits which target the vulnerabilities identified at step 2.

  An exploit is a concrete means of triggering a vulnerability in order to gain control or disable the target.
- Step 4: Use the exploits identified at step 3 to take control over one of more of the targets or disable them.